# Organization-level Feature Dependency to forecasting for accessing ForecastCategory and ForecastCategoryName

Tags: apex, managed-package

​
I have realised that my package is depending on the forecasting feature when it has never been depending on it. Going through the code it looks like accessing ForecastCategory and ForecastCategoryName from Opportunity is creating that dependency.
Is there any change in the last release that can make this to happen? That code has been there for many months and the dependency has never been there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is primarily Lightning base, W`18 introduced a Forecast related feature called [Change Opportunity Forecast Category](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_oppty_forecast_cat.htm?edition=&impact=) that allows users to change an opportunity’s forecast category regardless of its stage. This sounds like a feature that would introduce the dependency you're seeing in your managed package.